# How do i do a dynamic drop down that sorts items by price

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-select

So im trying to do a dynamic drop down that when a type of sorting is chosen the products get sorted in the controller and the page gets reloaded with the sorted database items

This is my HTML :

```
<div class="sorting">
    <select>
        <option value="1">Default sorting</option>
            <option value="1">Price low to high</option>
        <option value="1">Price high to low</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And this is my product controller with the action :

```
public IActionResult Index(string category)
        {
            IndexVM model = new IndexVM();

            model.products = productRepository.getProducts(category);
            model.categoryType = category;
            model.allItemsCount = model.products.Count;
            model.raceChipsCount = productRepository.getCategoryItemsCount("Chip tuning");
            model.carInteriorCount = productRepository.getCategoryItemsCount("Car interior");
            model.ExhaustSystemsCount = productRepository.getCategoryItemsCount("Exhaust system");
            model.gearBoxesCount = productRepository.getCategoryItemsCount("Gear boxes");
            model.enginePartsCount = productRepository.getCategoryItemsCount("Engine parts");

            return View(model);
        }
```

Basicly all i want is when a type of sorting is chosen to dynamicly redirect me to the Index action without pressing any submit button or anything. Im sorry if the code that i post is not so correct.

Comment: Ideally this would be done with AJAX instead of reloading the page.  But one thing you could do is attach a JavaScript handler to the `<select>` element's `change` event and, when the value changes, redirect the user to the URL with the value on the query string.  Or if this should be a POST request then that event handler could submit a `<form>` that wraps the `<select>` element.

Comment: @David can show me a piece of code or an example of how to attach the javascript handler

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#myDropdown").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: [your url to action],
        data: { category: this.value },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#ResultsDiv').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Let's make some assumptions:

1. Place id="myDropdown" to your select
2. Each option must have a different value (now they all have "1")
3. You must have a div with id = "ResultsDiv" inside of which you will load the ajax response.
4. Your must return a partial view with the necessary text fields to display your results.

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the answer as the correct one for future visitors.